# How do I change the value of a data cell just for a query. I cant seem to translate this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Create a list of all passengers (listing both first name and last name) and a comment stating whether they are a child or adult. The comment field should be titled ‘Age’ and should be correct at the time that the query is run. A child is 18years of age.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, 
    TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), birthdate)/365),0) AS age
FROM Emp
WHERE IF TRUNCATE(((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), birthdate)/365),0)>= 18 CONVERT "Adult" ELSE "Child" ;
```

Comment: Your SQL statement has syntax errors in it. For instance, the * should have a comma after it. Secondly, your where clause is improper. If you want a value returned, it needs to be between the SELECT and the FROM, IOW, in your column list. To determine age, you should use a function that returns the difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and birthdate. MySQL has several functions that will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should move that if/else logic to the list of selected columns. The (or sometimes one) correct way to use such conditional output is to use a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname, 
       CASE
         WHEN datediff(current_timestamp(), birthdate) / 365 >= 18 THEN
           'Adult'
         WHEN datediff(current_timestamp(), birthdate) / 365 >= 0 THEN
           'Child'
       END
       FROM emp;
```